# Axios post method refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, fetch

So I got this problem whenever I post something in my database on localhost with Axios, the page gets refreshed automatically. Searched the internet for the same problem, but didn't really find anything, everything was on the HTML form things and I don't really have a form on my page.

codepen: https://codepen.io/shotaivanidze/pen/PooLNPZ

Here is a JSON database:

```
 {
  "tags": [
    {
      "title": "test 1",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "test 2",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "title": "test 3",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "title": "test 4",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "title": "test 5",
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "title": "test 6",
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "title": "test 7",
      "id": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "I don't really have a form on my page"  — What does that mean? Do you or don't you?

Comment: "Axios post method refreshes the page" — It doesn't. Something else that happens at around the same time might, but Axios won't.

Comment: I don't have a form on my page, everything you see is actually generated from JS file. I only have 1 text type input.

Comment: @Quentin  After ".then" the page refreshes, I couldn't find any reason why does this happen that's why I am asking it here...

Comment: Have you tried to prevent the default browser action in your `keydown` event handler ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes I did, nothing changed. Also, preventdefault makes input useless on keydown event, as I can't type anything after.

Comment: I've just added axios.delete on span click event, and it refreshes the page as well after removing an item from the database.

Comment: Perhaps if you can provide CodePen or JSFiddle we will be able to better help you.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Added codepen link in the main post.